# Not able to get desired result from lookbehind in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a pattern which allows me to find a year of four digits. But I do not want to get results in which year is preceded by month e.g "This is Jan 2009" should not give any result, but "This is 2009" should return 2009. I use findall with lookbehind at Jan|Feb but I get 'an 2009' instead of blank. What am I missing? How to do It?

Comment: My regex is re.findall(r'(?<!Jan|Feb) [a-z]* \d{4}',"This is Jan 2009")

Comment: Why did you delete your code?  The question is pretty much unanswerable in its current form.  Anyway, the problem is in that `[a-z]*` part which is allowing anything consisting of lower case letters to match.

Comment: [a-z]* is added because I want not to match even if year is preceded by January|Feburary. If I use re.findall(r'(?:Jan|Feb) [a-z]* \d{4}',"This is Jan 2009"), I match Jan 2009 as well as January 2009. All I want is not to match year if year is preceded by Jan|Feb|January and so on. For this I cahnged ?: to ?<!. How to achieve this purpose otherwise? I did not delete code. It was not getting written somehow. So I posted this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Any otherwise matching string preceded by a string matching the negative lookbehind is not matched.

In your current regex, `[a-z]* \d{4}` matches `"an 2009"`.

The negative lookbehind `'(?<!Jan|Feb)'` does not match the `"This is J"` part, so it is not triggered.

If you remove `'[a-z]*'` from the regex, then no match will be returned on your test string.

To fix such problems:

First, write the match you want `\d{4}`

Then, write what you don't want `(?<!Jan |Feb )`

That is `(?<!Jan |Feb )\d{4}`

Comment: [a-z]* is added because I want not to match even if year is preceded by January|Feburary. How do I match year only not preceded by Jan|Jan.|January|/|- . If I write January in or operation with Jan, I get an error that negative lookbehind should be of same length. How should I proceed?

Comment: You can concatenate like this `re.findall('(?<!Jan )(?<!January )\d{4}', "This says Jan 2004, January 2005, and 2006")` I would do something equivalent to `reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, map(lambda x: "(?<!" + x + ")","January Jan February Feb".split()))` to get the first part.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

(?i)(?<!jan|feb)(?<!uary)\s+[0-9]*[0-9]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This generalized example should work for the cases you mentioned in your question above (edited to account for full month names):

INPUTS:

```
'This is 2009'
'This is Jan 2009'
```

REGEX:

```
re.findall(r'(?:\b[^A-Z][a-z]+\s)(\d{4})', text))
```

OUTPUTS:

```
['2009']
[]
```

EXPLANATION:

?: indicates a non-capturing group, therefore it will not be included in the output

\b asserts a word boundary

^[A-Z] asserts that the word does not start with a capital letter

[a-z]+ asserts that it is followed by one or more lowercase letters

\s accounts for any whitespace character

(\d{4}) asserts a capturing group for a digit (\d) for four occurrences {4}